# How to color a specific amount of rows from a table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<style>     
    #font{
        font-size: 20px;
        color:#0000cd;
    }
    tr:nth-child(n+7) {
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
    }                  
    table {
       border-spacing: 0;
    }
</style>
```

How do I color only a specific number of rows? 
here only the first 7 lines of my display is white and the rest grey. i want 7 lines white, 7 grey, 7 white, 7 grey and so on...

Comment: simply add a common class to 7 of them and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```css
.table>span {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.table>span:nth-child(14n + 1),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 2),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 3),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 4),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 5),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 6),
.table>span:nth-child(14n + 7) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: am pretty sure i can optimize the selector, but am not finding the trick :p

Comment: I don't think that it is optimizable. I could be wrong, but am I quite sure that it is not possible

Comment: @vals yes this is what i think too .. i tried a lot of ways but at the end i am always having a complex selector as long as this one