# CSS to target elements in set of number

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any way in CSS to target elements in set of number?
Like if I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>Child 1</li>
    <li>Child 2</li>
    <li>Child 3</li>
    <li>Child 4</li>
    <li>Child 5</li>
    <li>Child 6</li>
    <li>Child 7</li>
    <li>Child 8</li>
    <li>Child 9</li>
    <li>Child 10</li>
  </ul>
```

So, I want to style first 3 `li` with `color:red` then next 3 `li` with `color:blue` and then repeat.

I am not sure if its possible with `:nth`.

Trying something like this but its not helping

```
li:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: You need you use script for that if you dont know how many items you have.

Comment: So, CSS can't help in this case?

Comment: Why people are down voting? I am discussing my problem with each possible information I have. I have explained it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` but you'll need to setup two sets of rules, both for selecting groups of three elements at a time.

```css
li:nth-child(3n),li:nth-child(3n-1),li:nth-child(3n-2) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(6n),li:nth-child(6n-1),li:nth-child(6n-2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Child 1</li>
  <li>Child 2</li>
  <li>Child 3</li>
  <li>Child 4</li>
  <li>Child 5</li>
  <li>Child 6</li>
  <li>Child 7</li>
  <li>Child 8</li>
  <li>Child 9</li>
  <li>Child 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: though, somebody have already solved this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832188/how-to-color-a-specific-amount-of-rows-from-a-table .. your solution is also correct. Thanks.

Comment: you may optimize by having a general rule and keeping only the selector of the first set

Answer (score 3):

You can set a default color for `li`'s and *style* just the last (or the first) three every set of 6 elements in a row, differently:

```css
li {color: red}

li:nth-child(6n+4), 
li:nth-child(6n+5), 
li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Child 1</li>
  <li>Child 2</li>
  <li>Child 3</li>
  <li>Child 4</li>
  <li>Child 5</li>
  <li>Child 6</li>
  <li>Child 7</li>
  <li>Child 8</li>
  <li>Child 9</li>
  <li>Child 10</li>
</ul>
```